# ¿Como puedo contar espacios de un String?

Tags: c++, c

tengo el siguiente codigo en c++ y desarrolle una funcion para contar los espacios que aparecen en la cadena, pero me retorna 0, y no se porque,estuve revisando la guia de [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) y no encontre alguna funcion que me permita contar los espacios en c++,creo que tambien podria ser un error quizas de como este enviando los datos a la funcion,tambien voy a llamar a la funcion varias veces, asi que ¿no se si deberia pasar los parametros como puntero o como referencia?

```
void contador_de_palabras(string s,int espacios){

    for (int i = 0; i <= (int) s.length(); ++i){

        if (s[i] == ' '){

            espacios++;

         }

     }

 } 
int main( ){


    int espacios = 0;
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);

    cout<<s<<endl;

    contador_de_palabras(s,espacios);

    cout<<"espacios:"<<espacios;


    
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como tú dices al final de tu pregunta, debes pasar `ìnt espacios` por referencia, para esto usas el sufijo `&`:

```
void contador_de_palabras(string s,int& espacios){
//Todo el resto del código se mantiene igual
```

Debes recordar que un int, por default se pasa por valor. Entonces el parametro `espacios` es una "copia" local dentro la función, que no modifica la original. Caso contrario sucede cuando pasas por referencia.

En todo caso, me parece mejor opción retornar el valor:

```
int contador_de_palabras(string s){
   int espacios=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (int) s.length(); ++i){
        if (s[i] == ' '){
            espacios++;
         }
     }
    return espacios;
 } 
int main() 
{
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    int espacios = contador_de_palabras(s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    cout<<"espacios:"<<espacios;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pero no necesito que la funcion retorne valor ,necesito que pase el parametro, y cuando pase el parametro en la funcion principal espacios sea igual a el valor de los espacios

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo Eso lo haces con el primer código que te puse `int& espacios` , es decir solo te falta agregar el `&` y listo. De todas maneras te insisto que para tu caso, lo que veo más correcto, es que la función retorne un valor.

Answer (score 1):

Para casos como este, siempre es mejor usar algoritmos estándar en lugar de implementarlos uno mismo (son más fáciles de usar y casi siempre **son más eficientes**). Para contar elementos dentro de un contenedor tienes [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) (definido en [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)).

Es tan sencillo que en **una sola línea** ya tienes el numero de espacios:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    int espacios = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ');
    std::cout << "Espacios: " << espacios;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acabo de ver lo que escribiste aquí: "estuve revisando la guia de string y no encontre alguna funcion que me permita contar los espacios". Funciones que pueden actuar sobre varios tipos de contenedor (como `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc.) normalmente las puedes encontrar en la librería de algoritmos y no en la pagina del contenedor en cuestión, es por eso que a veces uno piensa que "faltan" funciones. Espero que esto te sirva (cuando yo lo encontré, fue la solución a muchos problemas).

Comment: muchas gracias, no so sabia que se podia hacer de forma tan automatica.

Comment: ¿que mas funciones son asi de utiles ?

Comment: `std::for_each`, `std::search`, `std::move`, `std::fill`, etc. Los puedes encontrar junto a muchos más [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).